# Escrever em arquivo .txt utilizando JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

Eu possuo um formulário `HTML` bem simples (estou utilizando ele apenas para testes)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Form</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="email" placeholder="Digite o seu email" class="email">
        <input type="password" placeholder="Digite a sua senha" class="senha">
        <input type="button" value="enviar" class="confirma" onclick="MinhaFuncao()">
    </body>
</html>
```

Reparem que na antepenúltima linha (linha 12) o meu botão possui uma função `JS` que até o momento está assim:

```
function MinhaFuncao(){
      var email = document.getElementById('email').value
      var senha = document.getElementById('senha').value
}
```

O que eu gostaria de fazer é de alguma forma pegar esses valores e escreve-los num arquivo .txt

Infelizmente tenho que realmente utilizar um txt.

Se tal ato não for possível com JavaScript, existe alguma forma de passar as informações do formulário para um arquivo `python` ou `C++`?

Comment: por razões de segurando o navegador não pode escrever arquivos, pode criar um codigo "server side" em python por exemplo, que receba uma requisição http, pode se ajax por exemplo, e ai sim o python pode gravar  um arquivo, mas note que pode não ser na mesma máquina do usuário

Comment: O máximo que consigo fazer é criar e exibir um link(ancora) no corpo do seu documento HTML cujo o usuário possa clicar com o botão direito do mouse e escolher salvar esse link como e o que for salvo é um documento de texto(ou qualquer outra coisa) gerado dinamicamente. Não sei se isso o serve.

Answer (score 0):

No JavaScript infelizmente não é possível fazer esse tipo de coisa(pelo menos não no cliente), em vez disso tente mandar as informações para um servidor utilizando o Ajax.
Segue um exemplo:

```
function getInformacaoQualquer() {
createRequest();
var url = "getInformacaoQualquerDoServidor-ajax.php";
request.open("GET", url, true);
request.onreadystatechange = atualizaPagina;
request.send(null);
}
```

Esse exemplo eu tirei do linha do código, da uma olhada que talvez te ajude:
http://www.linhadecodigo.com.br/artigo/3585/ajax-basico-introducao.aspx